# Can we create a SSIS package with BIDS 2008 R2 that can be installed on SQL server 2005

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to create a SSIS package using BIDS 2008 R2 on Windows 7. Is there anyway that we can create a SSIS package using BIDS 2008 R2 that is compatible and can be installed on SSIS 2005.

Please advise.

Comment: What do you mean by "installed".. is it related with deployment or open project with BIDS 2005.

Comment: I mean deploying the package on SSIS 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run SSIS package on a release that is below the developed level of the package, so it is not possible to deploy from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008 since SSIS packages are not backwards compatible.Same should apply for 2008R2.

MSDN documentaion:

> On an instance of SQL Server 2014, you can import packages from an
>   instance of SQL Server 2005 or from an instance of SQL Server 2008,
>   but you cannot export packages to an instance of SQL Server 2005 or to
>   an instance of SQL Server 2008.
>
> On an instance of SQL Server 2005 or an instance of SQL Server 2008,
>   you cannot import packages from, nor export packages to, an instance
>   of SQL Server 2014.

You cannot deploy/execute a 2008 package to SSIS 2005. You will need to get SSIS 2008 installed in order to deploy those packages. This does not mean that the databases need to be upgraded to 2008, just that an Instance of SSIS 2008 needs to be out there for you to deploy. If you store your packages in msdb, you may also need to upgrade an instance of SQL server to 2008.

- [Interoperability and Coexistence (Integration Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577(v=sql.105).aspx)